# PHP get error Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'

Tags: php, linux, odbc, ubuntu-16.04

I share the solution I found to the error above, hoping it will be useful.

After last update of my Ubuntu 16.04 all my queries to an MS SQL DB began to fail. The problem was at the connection statement.

The root of the problem is that Microsoft updated the ODBC driver to version 17 and during update (with apt-get update/upgrade) version 13 was deleted from the system and sqlsrv module of php wasn't updated accordingly and didn't work with version 17.

Solution: downgrade to version 13. What I did was:

Download version 13 of the driver:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/8/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql/msodbcsql_13.1.9.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Install the driver:

```
sudo dpkg -i msodbcsql_13.1.9.2-1_amd64.deb
```

That's all.

Comment: Is there a question here?